# How did Pam lose so much weight so quickly?

Tags: archer

Here is the Archer character Pam Poovey as she appears in seasons 1 through 4:

[image]

And here is Pam in season 5:

[image]

How and why did she lose so much weight so quickly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170430190125/http://www.xojane.com/entertainment/skinny-pam-poovey-archer) (disapproving!) article:

> Pam’s developed a cocaine addiction as a result of a flight she spent
>   wrapped in a body cast made of cocaine (don’t bother asking), and in
>   the most recent episode, she was revealed to have lost a bunch of
>   weight, ostensibly as a result of her new habit.

Comment: +1 and thanks!  I should have guessed that that had something to do with it.  Is there any conclusive evidence?

Comment: @WadCheber they refer to it in the show, e.g. *"I guess we have to decide if we want regular lame Cheryl and a Pam who's not gonna overdose on cocaine and die, or potentially famous country singer Cheryl and a Pam who tits."*

Comment: Link is broken, but I believe that the above occurs during Season 5 (Archer Vice) Episode 2.

Comment: @Raj fixed it with an archive.org link, thanks for pointing it out. And yes, the cocaine body cast is worn during s05e02: https://archer.fandom.com/wiki/Archer_Vice:_A_Kiss_While_Dying

Comment: I seem to recall her Pam mentioning early in season 6 that once she broke her cocaine habit, she returned to her unhealthy eating habits instead, explaining both her loss and subsequent regain of weight.